# Environment problem

Tags: fonts, environments, section-titles

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage
[
        a4paper,% other options: a3paper, a5paper, etc
        left=2.54cm,
        right=2.54cm,
        top=2.54cm,
        bottom=2.54cm,
        % use vmargin=2cm to make vertical margins equal to 2cm.
        % us  hmargin=3cm to make horizontal margins equal to 3cm.
        % use margin=3cm to make all margins  equal to 3cm.
]
{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
%% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}


\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm} %harvard referencing style

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\title{\vspace{-2cm} Simulation Project Report}
\author{\textbf{Authors: Jing Ting Chong, Ishaan Singh Jolly}}


\date{}
\begin{document}
Environment Problem

\end{document}
```

There seems to be several issues with my environment, I don't quite understand why and what is happening to my latex. I think there is a problem with my font, and I cannot set font size to to my section and subsection using this --

```
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

Comment: you have posted a large example using dozens of packages which does not actually have any code that shows your problem. Then you have another fragment that uses some commands from an unnamed package (titlesec perhaps?) which isn't used in yoru first document.

Comment: your title and tagging implies your question is about an environment (`\begin{...}...\end{..}` but I don't think you mean that?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think I mean about the packages, very certainly, which are affecting my environment.

Comment: "environment" has a specific meaning in latex `\begin{something}...\end{somenthing}` so using environment to mean "your general settings" is misleading (and the environments tag is wrong) but it is completey unclear what is your question, if it is about customising section headings make an example that has a section heading (and does not have all the packages that are not relevant to your question) and  say what error you got. Simply saying "environment problem" is not a question.

Comment: Should I edit the question David ?

Comment: yes I have no idea what your question is, I am probably not the only one, so if you want to get an answer, then  editing the questiion to have an example that shows your problem would help.

Comment: If you include `\usepackage{titlesec}` it should probably do what you want. Or it should do what you probably want :)